# In Spring MVC 3.0.5 controller JPA entity not getting persisted to the database

Tags: spring, jpa

In the code below, persist() returns w/o an exception but the entity is not stored in the database.

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String form() {
        EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager();
        TaxRates t = new TaxRates();
        t.setCountry("US");
        // set more properties
        em.persist(t);
        em.close();
        ...
 }
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="TT-SpringMVCPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    ...
    <class>com.sajee.db.TaxRates</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1234/mydb"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Password1"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't need any transaction support or any fancy enterprise feature support.  I simply want to create an entity and save it to the database.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`persist()` doesn't write your object to the database immediately. Instead, it marks your object as *persistent*, so that it will be written to the database before transaction commit (or before executing a query, or during explicit `flush()` operation).

So, even if you don't need transactional behaviour you still have to manage transactions. You can do it manually as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public String form() { 
        EntityManager em = this.emf.createEntityManager(); 
        TaxRates t = new TaxRates(); 
        t.setCountry("US"); 
        // set more properties 
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(t); 
        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close(); 
        ... 
}
```

But [Spring's declarative transaction support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa) is a more convenient way to do it.